# Como o php garante um unico session_id?

Tags: php, session, hash, restrição-único

Qual algorítimo usado para garantir um único `session_id()`? Queria saber como é a criação e a verificação para garantir que tal ID não colida com outro já existente?

Preciso criar alguns *hashes*, mas tenho receio de que uma hora duas ou mais entradas possam criar o mesmo hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O comportamento padrão do PHP é utilizar o hash `md5` ou `sha1` de alguns valores obtidos no momento da geração do ID:

- IP do cliente;
- Horário atual;
- Número aleatório qualquer (pode ser fornecido por um PRNG do SO, como `/dev/urandom`).

É possível haver colisão? Sim! Como se é conhecido, tanto o MD5 quanto o SHA1 são inseguros. Mas o objetivo é simplesmente tornar computacionalmente caro ataques de força bruta. Tanto que no caso do PHP, não há qualquer tratamento de colisão.

No caso de implementar uma estrutura de dados que objetive a busca rápida de valores (como Hash Table), este não é o melhor jeito. Deve-se considerar apenas o dado propriamente dito no Hash. Do contrário, você não irá conseguir recuperar seus dados.

A implementação de tratamento de colisão é obrigatória na maioria dos casos, cabendo a você decidir qual das implementações utilizar. O algortímo de tratamento de colisão pode ou não ser adequado de acordo com a natureza das operações que serão realizadas.

**Possível Tratamento de Colisão no PHP**

No caso do PHP, acredito que simplesmente gerar novamente um novo hash, seja o suficiente. Isto funciona pois apesar do IP do cliente continuar igual, o número aleatório com certeza (bom... espera-se, né?) irá mudar, e o horário provavelmente irá mudar também. Então não vejo motivo em repetir o procedimento até que uma colisão não ocorra.

Não vou discutir a colisão no caso de dados pois acredito não ser do domínio do questionamento.

Comment: Eu não sabia que o PHP não tratava colisão. O problema é ter um campo UNIQUE e em algum momento colidir o HASH. Qual seria o 'tratamento' pro caso?

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Quando você diz "PHP não trata essa colisão" você se refere à manipulação das sessions?

Comment: Exatamente. Se o PHP gerar dois ID's de sessão iguais, ele não vai saber, e a sessão será compartilhada pelos dois clientes. Isso pode gerar problemas de todos os tipos, dependendo da sua aplicação (digamos que isso é o inferno para aplicações bancárias e e-commerces).

Comment: Tem alguma referência pra leitura? Esse é o tipo de falha catastrófica.

Comment: Procurando por "php session collision" no Goole, vêm alguns resultados. Fora isso, já aconteceu comigo em um dos meus clientes. O dano foi pequeno (crash de uma aplicação CGI de terceiro), e descobri apenas porque guardávamos um log extenso de acesso. Após isto, estudei o código fonte, na época da versão 4.X, e hoje conferi na versão 5 se ainda há o problema. Estas são minhas únicas referências. Se você descobrir algo mais, por favor compartilhe =]

Answer (score 2):

Eu geralmente utilizo o IP do usuário (`$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`) com o timestamp em segundos do momento da criação da sessão utilizando a função [time()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.time.php) juntamente com alguma palavra chave, tudo isso converto pra md5 ([md5()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.md5.php)) ou sha1 ([sha1()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sha1.php)) e crio a minha hash!

Para uma mais precisa ainda, pode utilizar a função [microtime()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.microtime.php) que retorna o tempo em microsegundos, o que torna mais difícil (talvez impossível) existir uma hash igual, principalmente concatenando com o ip.

Espero que ajude.

Abraços

Comment: Na verdade eu tenho uma sequencia numérica baseada no TS junto com 10 numeroa aleatórios, mas usar md5 acaba criando a possibilidade de colisão. Por isso queria saber a garantia da `SESSION`. Mas valeu pela resposta.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Colisões acidentais de MD5 são muito improváveis (ao passo que colisões *intencionais*, i.e. maliciosas, são relativamente simples de produzir), desde é claro que os dados hashedos sejam distintos (essa que é a parte difícil).

Comment: @mgibsonbr Lei de Murphy... muito improvável quer dizer que vai acontecer (rs). Se houver colisão não vou poder contornar o problema...

Comment: Um UUID aleatório possui 122 bits (<16 bytes, metade de um MD5). Se você gerar algumas dezenas de trilhões desses num ano, a chance de uma colisão é mais ou menos a mesma de você ser atingido por um meteorito nesse mesmo período... Não vou dar mais palpite, pois não tenho conhecimento suficiente pra dizer nada com segurança, mas de um modo geral eu afirmo que os hashes de dados distintos também serão distintos, mesmo para um algoritmo "quebrado" como o MD5 (de novo, a menos que essa colisão tenha sido feita propositalmente).

Answer (score 2):

Para ver como o identificador é gerado, basta [**olhar no código**](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d9bfe06194ae8f760cb43a3e7120d0503f327398/ext/session/session.c#L284), basicamente ele é baseado em [MD5](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) por padrão, mas pode ser `SHA1` ou outra.

Outros ingredientes:

- Endereço IP do cliente - [**L298**](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d9bfe06194ae8f760cb43a3e7120d0503f327398/ext/session/session.c#L298).
- Horário atual - [**L300**](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d9bfe06194ae8f760cb43a3e7120d0503f327398/ext/session/session.c#L300)
- Um gerador de número aleatório - [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) - [**L349**](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d9bfe06194ae8f760cb43a3e7120d0503f327398/ext/session/session.c#L349)

  - Se o sistema operacional tiver uma fonte aleatória específico do sistema operacional, o mesmo é usado, por exemplo `/dev/urandom` - [**L815**](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d9bfe06194ae8f760cb43a3e7120d0503f327398/ext/session/session.c#L815)

Comment: O meu `PHPSESSID` gera uma string de 26, e usando `MD5` gera uma string de 32. Sendo criado com base em `MD5` não deveria manter o comprimento da string?

Comment: @PapaCharlie Interessante. Segundo essa [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27269145/1608936) do SO, essa característica vai depender do [manipulador de sessão](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php) usado, e segundo [essa thread](http://community.sitepoint.com/t/phpsessid-character-length-32-in-5-2-x-26-in-5-3-x/63587) do *sitepoint*, o comprimento é de *32* caracteres no PHP *5.2*, já no *5.3*, é de *26*. Estou procurando mais para saber se isso é verdade mesmo. =)

Comment: Aqui é `5.4.28` e não alterei nenhuma config da session. Hipoteticamente; monta-se um sistema esperando um SESSIONID baseado em HASH com comprimento de 32, e quando vai executar são só 26. PHP sempre surpreendendo.